# can i define global variables for an email in eloqua

Tags: oracle, email, html-email, eloqua

I am using eloqua for email marketing and i do not see any way to define global variables in the email. Is there any script that eloqua uses that i can use to define some global variables at the top of the email so i do not have to define values several times in the html?

I am looking to define variables like this:

```
var mylink = "www.google.com";

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>  </head>
  <body>
<a href="@mylink">Visit Website</a>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I know eloqua does content blocks. Tried that?

Comment: Yes - I know about content blocks that is only for HTML. I am looking for a way to create variables at the top of the email in Eloqua so that variable values can be passed to HTML like defining hyperlink source in a variable and use that variable in the HTML? I am assuming by content blocks, you mean dynamic content blocks. I am also interested in learning if there is any way to create conditions via any script or code directly in the HTML of the email instead of using dynamic blocks. If there are a lot of conditions, manually creating each block can be a very time consuming process.

Comment: The problem is even if you create an email that is html, and be able to add javascript to it, be sure that outlook will not render it as outlook is using ms word as a rendering engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloqua actively blocks java scripting in emails[1].

What you are attempting is bypassing eloqua built in functions.

Either utilize the field merge or dynamic content modules to achieve your desired outcome.
If you have a range of values, picklists can be very powerful.

[1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/Emails/HTMLemailCodeRequirements.htm) https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/eloqua-user/Help/Emails/HTMLemailCodeRequirements.ht